# delete everything before pattern including pattern using awk or sed

Tags: unix, awk, sed, pattern-matching

```
aaa aaaa aaaa aaaa
sss ssss ssss ssss
ddd dddd dddd dddd
fff ffff ffff ffff
abc pattern asd fde 
111 222 333 444 555
666 777 888 999 000
```

Desired output : If the

```
111 222 333 444 555
666 777 888 999 000
```

Comment: Try not to think and specify problems in terms of what you want to delete from a file but instead in terms of what you want to select from a file - it often makes a difference to the readability, maintainability, etc. of the solutions you (and we) come up with to your problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just set a flag whenever the pattern is found. From that moment on, print the lines:

```
$ awk 'p; /pattern/ {p=1}' file
111 222 333 444 555
666 777 888 999 000
```

Or also

```
awk '/pattern/ {p=1;next}p' file
```

It looks for `pattern` in each line. When it is found, the variable `p` is set to 1. The tricky point is that lines are just printed when `p>0`, so that the following lines will be printed.

This is a specific case of [How to select lines between two patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38972737/1983854) when there is no such second pattern.

Comment: `next` could be saved...  `awk 'p;/pattern/{p=1}'`  ;)

Comment: I must say, your original answer is easier to read and understand. particularly if the script was long.

Comment: awk 'p; /pattern/ {p=1}' file

Comment: Beware though that when pattern isn't found at all, this deletes everything.

Comment: @MartinvonWittich you are right. To prevent this, you can read the file twice: once to see if the pattern is found and set a flag. Then, to print it either completely or from the pattern: `awk 'FNR==NR {if (/pattern/) found=1; next} p || !found; /pattern/ {p=1}' file file`

Answer (score 8):

```
sed '1,/pattern/d' file
```

works for your example.

```
sed '0,/pattern/d' file
```

is more reliable.

Comment: Yes. Unless `pattern` is found in first line. Better begin the range in `0`.

Comment: Beware though that when pattern isn't found at all, this deletes everything.

Answer (score 2):

Another one `sed` solution:

```
sed ':loop;/pattern/{d};N;b loop' file.txt
```

Comment: This seems to be the only solution that doesn't delete everything when the pattern isn't found.