# search for last occurrence of the pattern in a file and delete everything after that excluding pattern line

Tags: unix, sed, awk, html-table

I am trying to search for last occurrence of the pattern in the file and delete everything after the line containing last pattern. I wonder if its possible using awk or sed. thanks in Advance.

```
aaaaaa bbbbb cccccc
aaaaaa pattern dddddd
eeeeee fffff gggg
qqqq eeee rrrr
```

desired output:

```
aaaaaa bbbbb cccccc
aaaaaa pattern dddddd
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`tac` to the rescue:

```
$ tac b | awk '/pattern/ {p=1}p' | tac
aaaaaa bbbbb cccccc
aaaaaa pattern dddddd
```

- `tac` does concatenate and print the file in reverse.
- the `awk` code is explained in my answer to your previous question, [delete everything before pattern including pattern using awk or sed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19047354/1983854).

Another example:

```
$ cat a
aaaaaa bbbbb cccccc
aaaaaa pattern dddddd
eeeeee fffff gggg
aaaaaa pattern dddddd
qqqq eeee rrrr
$ tac a | awk '/pattern/ {p=1}p' | tac
aaaaaa bbbbb cccccc
aaaaaa pattern dddddd
eeeeee fffff gggg
aaaaaa pattern dddddd
```

Comment: Also: `tac a | sed -n '/pattern/,$p' | tac`

Comment: what if I want to search for first pattern and delte everything above it including the pattern line ?

Comment: @user2809888 this is what you asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19047312/delete-everything-before-pattern-including-pattern-using-awk-or-sed

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '
    BEGIN { ARGV[ARGC++] = ARGV[ARGC-1] }
    NR==FNR { if (/pattern/) lastLine = NR; next }
    { print }
    FNR == lastLine { exit }
' file
```

To demonstrate how postfix works above (see comments below):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ i=3; a[i++] = i; for (j in a) print j, a[j]; print i }'
3 3
4
```

Comment: I can always learn things from your answer, I think this time too. Can you explain the begin block? I knew that here we want to read the input file twice by append a ARGV. but this line I cannot understand: `ARGV[ARGC++] = ARGV[ARGC-1]` say, we have `awk '..' file` then we have `ARGC=2; V[0]=awk; V[1]=file` now we do `V[ARGC++]...` then we assign `V[2]=something` now the `ARGC` is 3. the right side, `ARGV[ARGC-1]` is actually `V[3-1]` but `V[2]` is empty. why after `ARGC++` didn't change the `ARGC`?

Comment: @Kent the only "tricky" part is that `++` is a postfix operator and so doesn't occur until AFTER the whole statement is evaluated so it's equivalent to `ARGV[ARGC] = ARGV[ARGC-1]; ARGC++`, i.e. ARGC retains its original value until after the assignment.

Comment: @Kent I updated my answer just to show how postifx works in a small script.

Comment: thank you so much, I tested it a bit just now `awk 'BEGIN{x=5;a[x++]=x;print a[5]}'` it printed 5, not 6. it is interesting. not like other programming languages. good to know. thank you for the answer and the explanation. +1, ++1 ;)

Comment: I suspect the difference might be related to interpreted vs compiled languages. If I could get my `awkcc` to work, it'd be an interesting test!

Comment: I don't know so many languages. Python has no `x++`, I know in `java`, it works not like awk does.  I don't have much experience with `C` family, so I cannot tell, but I guess it would behave same as java.

Comment: @Kent I just discovered that it is implementation-dependent according to the bottom section of gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Increment-Ops.html. Sorry if I led you astray!

Answer (score 1):

I have this line, should work for your requirement:

```
awk '/pattern/{_=NR}{a[NR]=$0}END{for(i=1;i<=_;i++)print a[i]}' file
```

I did a small test:

```
kent$  cat f
aaaaaa bbbbb cccccc
aaaaaa pattern dddddd
eeeeee fffff gggg
qqqq eeee rrrr 
aaaaaa pattern dddddd
111
222

kent$  awk '/pattern/{_=NR}{a[NR]=$0}END{for(i=1;i<=_;i++)print a[i]}' f
aaaaaa bbbbb cccccc
aaaaaa pattern dddddd
eeeeee fffff gggg
qqqq eeee rrrr 
aaaaaa pattern dddddd
```

Comment: @fedorqui I found that too.. now it should give the right thing.

Comment: What does the `i<=_` part mean in `(i=1;i<=_;i++)`?

Comment: @EdMorton because it should be the *lastline* of matching. `_` looks like the last line. :D

Comment: I don't get it. How does `_` look like the last line? Not trying to be difficult, just honestly trying to understand as I seem to be missing the point.

Comment: what if I want to search for first pattern and delte everything above it including the pattern line ?

Comment: @user2809888 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19047312/delete-everything-before-pattern-including-pattern-using-awk-or-sed

Comment: Id did give thumbs down for this since the non intuitive variable `_` was used for no reason and no explanation. Using a common sense variable makes script easy to read and understand for all.

Comment: @Jotne You can have your own opinion for sure. I agree with you, `_` doesn't look like other common var names, easy to be read, but personally I don't think the answer deserves a downvote, even if it could be written better. 1) it works 2) corner cases were considered as well 3) `_` is a valid variable name in awk. that is, we can use it.  4) the `_` is underscore, for me it looks like the `Lastline in a file`. so I used it. Would you vote `awk` down too (if you could) since awk allows a var named `_` ? Or you can suggest, when should we use the var name `_`?

Comment: I wouldn't downvote it, but the intent of allowing `_` as a character in a name is to separate words in a general naming scheme (e.g. `foo_bar` vs `fooBar`) or to prefix names that are in some way "special" (e.g. local variables declared as function args, `foo(realArg, _localVar)`). In C, macro-local vars should start with `_` and compiler symbols with double `__` but there's no equivalent awk conventions. All entities in software should have a name that identifies what they are, as such you would never name any symbol `_` as that tells you nothing at all about the entity with that name.

Comment: I can not remove the downvote. I agree its a valid character, but a simple `b` would do.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/pattern/{x;/./p;d};x;/./!{x;b};x;H;$!d;x;P;d' file
```